# Now that I built Unity How do I Install it?

Tags: unity, compiling, customization, nux

Hello there I built my own custom unity 6.2 and I built it so that it is in my home directory. I like how it looks now and want to replace the unity that I have installed on my system with the one that I have just built.

More about the unity build

I used qtcreator to build it when it asked where I wanted to build It I gave it the path of

```
~Desktop/unity-6.2.0+bzr2624ubuntu0+762-build/
```

It builds and it is awesome I can run it and I love it. But I can not figure out how to install it.

Please let me know if you need extra info.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I just had to change the cmake install prefix But this is how I do it now

Please Note that this will install a new unity and will overwrite you old one.

Date that I wrote this 10/1/2012 
Ubuntu Version 12.10

1st) get the source code. we can make a place to build from , for this example I will use

```
~/Desktop/
```

get the source code

```
cd ~/Desktop
apt-get source unity
```

This will get all the source code, Or you can use bzr to get it

```
bzr branch lp:unity
```

Either way you are going to need it. You are also going to need qtcreator and all the build dependency's of Unity so

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
sudo apt-get build-dep unity
```

Next We open up Qt Creator,

[image]

Now We can open up are project (Unity in this case) But before we do this lets make a **Build dir**
So

```
cd ~/Desktop/unity-6.whatever
mkdir build
```

[image]

Now in Qt Creator we can open Unity . Go to File->open file

[image]

Next we will be asked what file we want to open up. We want to open 
***CMakeList.txt***

[image]

Next We will be asked what Build Directory we would like to use. This is why we set up the build dir in the projects top level. IE
    ~/Desktop/unity-6-whatever/build

And this is the Directory that we will choose Then we Press Next

[image]

Next we will be asked what Arguments we want to pass on to Cmake, Now because we are building from are sandboxed (~/Desktop/unity-6-whatever/build ) folder called build. Which is one directory below the top directory we need to use

```
../
```

and also because by default Unity build is set up to install to

```
/usr/local/
```

and not

```
/usr/
```

we need to also tell cmake that also So

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr
```

So all together

```
../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr
```

If all goes well it should set up build files to ~/Desktop/build as shown in the screen-shot

[image]

We can now Press the Finish Button. And We will get a screen that looks like this.

[image]

Now to build Unity and test are results. The first thing that we need to do is tell Qt-creator what we want to run after compile. We do this by clicking in the Icon that looks like a monitor and then select

***unity-standalone***

***NOTE:*** There are some issues with unity stand alone and it will not run as fast nor will it render graphics as good as when installed. But when you install on to system all will be ok. I am also unsure when Unity started using Unity-standalone as before 5.10 I was a Unity 2d kinda guy :)

[image]

Now we can Run Unity press ***ctrl+r*** (keyboard shortcut) to run and Unity will compile.

Or we can press the green arrow button also in QT-Creator to Run

[image]

Well Compiling (Running)  We can watch to see what is going on by pressing the

***Compile Output Button***

[image]

Once compile is done (takes a minute) Unity-Standalone should launch

[image]

Now we can play around with the Unity that we just built Go back to QT Creator and and Press the stop button. To Kill Unity-Standalone

[image]

Next we can start editing files if we like to make Unity more how we like

[image]

After editing we press 
***ctrl+s***  to save are work 
then Run it again 
***ctrl+r***

and once we have Unity the way that we want it We can do One of two things
Build a debian package of it. Or Install using make. Installing with make is easy.

```
cd ~/Desktop/unity-6-whatever/build/
make 
sudo make install
```

Now you can log in and out to restart and use your unity
If you want to make a debian package of it this is how you do it.

```
cd ~/Desktop/unity-6-whatever/build
make clean
cd ../
rm -r build
sudo apt-get install packaging-dev dh-make dpkg-dev
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -F
```

Then Look in the dir above where you are (~/Desktop) there should be all the packages there at this point if you made it correctly

Think that you got something that should be used by others ? or want to let your friends use it ? We can use launchpad for this. go to launchpad and make a repo  (ppa)

then

```
cd ~/Desktop/unity-6-whatever/
dch -i
```

enter in the changes that you have made and the version number and codename.Then save the file (changelog file)
then

```
debuild -S -sa
cd ../
dput ppa:YOUR_LP_NAME/YOUR_PPA_NAME unity-whatever.sources.change
```

and let launchpad build it for you.

***Now the easy way***
 to reset unity to default would be to purge it Nux and compiz and re-install

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove unity compiz libnux-3.0-*
```

then re-install

```
sudo apt-get install unity compiz libnux-3.0-*
```

and other ways that are listed on this page.

I hope that this helps and happy hacking